# How to find a Guest user cart details?

Tags: magento

I want to get the Guest user cart details in magento.
Suppose a user comes to Magento site and add a product to cart.Then again come to same product and again he wants to add the product to cart.Now I want to check  if the same guest user has already that product in the cart.

I am using following to get the guest user  details`$session=Mage::getModel('core/session');`

using  above code If I use `print_r(session)` then I get a visitor Id.

How Can I load the check out cart collection using this visitor ID to check If he already have that product in the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the items stored in the cart you can use:

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCart()->getItems()`

Then you can loop over all the items and check wether the id is already there.